# Scale down to a specific frequency on Ubuntu Linux 14 w/ Intel CPU

Tags: cpu, intel, cpu-frequency

I am trying to scale down one of the CPU frequencies. I am using Ubuntu 14 and Linux kernel 4.4. **I want to scale down the cpu3 frequency to 1.2 CONSTANT (no throttle)**.

**Things I have tried:**

1. I want to scale it down by booting with intel_pstate=disable in the /etc/default/grub but upon booting the cpu freqeuency module does not appear anymore. (as per the comments)

   cpupower -c 3 frequency-set -f 1.2
   Setting cpu: 3
   Error setting new values. Common errors:

   - Do you have proper administration rights? (super-user?) **Yes**
   - Is the governor you requested available and modprobed?
   - Trying to set an invalid policy?
   - Trying to set a specific frequency, but userspace governor is not available,
     for example because of hardware which cannot be set to a specific frequency
     or because the userspace governor isn't loaded? **Lack of userspace seems to be the problem**
2. Tried to assign the cpu3 powersave governor and the rest performance governor.  This way i could change the ranges. However the changes still appear on ALL the cpus

   cpupower -c 3 frequency-set --governor powersave --min 1200MHz --max  1200MHz
3. Tried assigning 1.2 to the maximum available frequency file but it generate an  error of invalid argument.cpupower -c 3 frequency-set --governor powersave --min 1200MHz --max 1200MHz
4. Can I install other drivers? The server I am working on is production. Real sensitive. Can't take any chances.

This is the current state of my PC.

```
Every 0.1s: cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "^[c]pu MHz"                                                                                                                                  

cpu MHz         : 2902.593
cpu MHz         : 2901.093
cpu MHz         : 2900.343
cpu MHz         : 2901.281
cpu MHz         : 2823.093
cpu MHz         : 2901.843
cpu MHz         : 2900.812
cpu MHz         : 2800.593
cpu MHz         : 2800.218
cpu MHz         : 2800.312
cpu MHz         : 2506.593
cpu MHz         : 2800.406
cpu MHz         : 2800.875
cpu MHz         : 2800.312
cpu MHz         : 2901.281
cpu MHz         : 2901.093
cpu MHz         : 2801.718
cpu MHz         : 2900.812
cpu MHz         : 2899.875
cpu MHz         : 2900.250
cpu MHz         : 2800.406
cpu MHz         : 2800.312
cpu MHz         : 2800.218
cpu MHz         : 2899.968
cpu MHz         : 2800.406
cpu MHz         : 2726.156
cpu MHz         : 2900.437
cpu MHz         : 2900.625
```

What can I do?

Comment: I had the same question once, and the answer  i think was to disable pstate kernel parameter. This allows you to use fixed frequency.... I will try to find the right command.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling

Comment: Looks like you need `userspace` governor to use specific frequency for a specific CPU core. What I suggested (in an answer which should be deleted soon because it's useless now) `sudo cpupower -c 3 frequency-set --governor powersave --min 1200MHz --max 1200MHz` won't work because min/max affect the governor itself, so `-c 3` has no effect, it will affect all CPUs and lock them to 1.2GHz at all times.

Answer (score 0):

On newer CPUs the command `cpupower` is not available any more.

It is not easily possible to scale down the CPU to a certain frequency, but in this blogpost, you find a script to disable turbo-boost: http://notepad2.blogspot.com/2014/11/a-script-to-turn-off-intel-cpu-turbo.html

(This will probably solve the issue for many searchers, that ended up here.)